# How to configure a mapping of collection types with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

For example, I've implemented two classes like these:

```
public class A
{
    public List<C> Items { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public IImmutableList<C> Items { get; set; }
}

public class C 
{
}
```

When I try to map `A` to `B` and vice versa, I get an exception because `List<string>` cannot be converted to `IImmutable<string>`.

Probably I could provide a mapping for `A<->B`, but since it'll be a very common pattern in my solution, I'd like to avoid to manually mapping each class that may fall into the same case.

Is there anyway I can generalize the whole mapping using **generic type definitions** from a collection type to another collection type?

### This is what I want to avoid

```
mapperConfig.CreateMap<A, B>()
    .ForMember(a => a.Items, opts => opts.Ignore())
    .AfterMap
    (
        (source, target) =>
        {
            target.Items = source.Items.ToImmutableList();
        }
    );
```